# Debian and RedHat dual boot

Tags: debian, rhel, dual-boot

I have been using Debian 10 for a while now, I thought of trying RHEL 8 for a change, and hence I dual booted the same. I was able to boot into rhel but now I am unable to boot into Debian. The last thing that happened is [ OK ] Started Gnome Display Manager. Can someone please help? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Install `os-prober` then run `grub2-mkconfig`  see [how to run `grub2-mkconfig` for Bios or UEFI.](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sec-customizing_the_grub_2_configuration_file#sec-Editing_a_Menu_Entry)